# Can casts be completely avoided with a good design?

Tags: c++, oop, casting

I'm wondering whether situation exists where casting is completely necessary.
I'm talking here about casts between classes, not basic types.

Is casting (be it C++ style like `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`, or plain C-style cast) a code smell? I can see how sometimes it's helpful, but I think it can also be avoided. Does casting break any OOP rules?

Comment: Avoiding casts completely isn't a wise decision. Good design minimizes them, but avoiding them leads to reinventing a worse form of type conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by *code smell* you mean that it should raise a flag in a code review, then they are a code smell. If you mean that they should never appear in code, then no, there are some fine uses of casts.

For an interesting example (I always find *type erasure* interesting), take a look at the implementation of `boost::any` where `dynamic_cast` is required to safely read from the stored value (unlike `union`s where you must guess the type and are limited)

Sketch:

```
struct any_base {
   virtual ~any_base() {}
};
template <typename T>
struct any_data : any_base {
   T value;
   any_data( T const & value ) : value(value) {}
};
struct any {
   any_base * data;
   any() : data() {}
   ~any() { delete data; }

   template <typename T>
   any( T const & v ) : data( new any_data<T>(v) {}
}
template <typename T>
T any_cast( any const & a ) {
   any_base<T> * p = dynamic_cast< any_base<T>* >( a.data );
   if ( !p ) throw invalid_cast();
   return *p;
}
```

Comment: How would you resolve this if you wanted to have any have data be a private member, now any_cast must be a friend, but that can't possibly work because the type T is not know in any...So does that mean that any::data must always be public?

Answer (score 4):

Not especially. Casts should be avoided whenever possible, but at the most fundamental level, there are regions of C++ that exist outside the realm of type safety, and casts are necessary. `dynamic_cast` is a special exception, specifically, it *can* be necessary even in a solid OOP design.

There are "that's imperfect" and there's "OMGWTF, Y U SO DUMB". Casts are just imperfect.

Comment: Can you provide an example where casts are necessary?

Answer (score 0):

The typical example is I/O: This is one of the few and only reasons to cast, and it also uses one of the only legitimate pointer types in C++: `char *`:

```
uint32_t n;
infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&n), sizeof n);
n *= 2;
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>)(&n), sizeof n);
```

Other "I/O-like" operations require a similar pattern, such as encryption or encoding conversion.

<sub>(The other legitimate pointer in C++ is `void *` when used in the context of allocation, but it shouldn't need to be cast: The C++ way to "convert" a memory pointer to an object pointer is via *construction*: `void * addr = get_memory();`, then `T * p = new (addr) T;`.)</sub>

Comment: I was referring to casts between classes, not basic types.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that casting cannot be completely avoided by good design because there are reasonable cases where casting is a good choice. Proxies are enormously useful and usually rely on implicit or explicit casting such as the following which does lazy evaluation.

```
template <class fn_t, class result_t>
class lazy_t {
    fn_t fn_;
public:

    lazy_t(fn_t fn) : fn_ (fn) { }

    operator result_t () { return fn_(); }
};
```

In this case the compiler can use implicit casting to perform lazy evaluation of a given function. I would consider the conversion operator a part of the public interface of the class.

dynamic_cast<> is also necessary in certain cases such as implementing multiple-dispatch. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch for more on this.

Sometimes your programs require complicated code. You can't always just stick to the simple, basic or "clean" elements of the language.